# Bootstrap v4 Beta, customizing gutters

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-4

Is there a way, to customizing grid gutters in each breakpoints?

I know, that Twitter pay dollars of millions to make Bootstrap v4 perfect and I don't want to reform everything in a day, but I'm just curious, that is there a way to make my custom gutters, not just only one.

Like: I want the gutter at large size to be `30px` , but on smaller devices I want it to be `24px` and on mobile `20px`

Comment: Looks like the gutter for each breakpoint mixin was removed from beta 1 https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/commit/b013b987b0b770434b3bc1ec61a7b9971a73aedb

Comment: @ZimSystem I just read it too in their repo https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/22944

Answer (score 1):

You can add your custom gutter like this :

```
.row.custom-gutter {
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

[class^='col'].custom-gutter,
[class*=' col'].custom-gutter {
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}
```

And then you'll have to update the padding on smaller devices with media queries.

Comment: This is perfect for me. And I never even thought to have both of those selectors for the col classes (^ and *) but that's definitely necessary. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to go on your-folder/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/**_variables.scss** and search :

```
// Grid columns
//
// Set the number of columns and specify the width of the gutters.

$grid-columns:                  12 !default;
$grid-gutter-width-base:        30px !default;
$grid-gutter-widths: (
  xs: $grid-gutter-width-base,
  sm: $grid-gutter-width-base,
  md: $grid-gutter-width-base,
  lg: $grid-gutter-width-base,
  xl: $grid-gutter-width-base
) !default;
```

You can also change the breakpoints :

```
// Grid breakpoints
//
// Define the minimum dimensions at which your layout will change,
// adapting to different screen sizes, for use in media queries.

$grid-breakpoints: (
  xs: 0,
  sm: 576px,
  md: 768px,
  lg: 992px,
  xl: 1200px
) !default;
@include _assert-ascending($grid-breakpoints, "$grid-breakpoints");
@include _assert-starts-at-zero($grid-breakpoints);
```

Comment: it would be good, but they removed it from the beta
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/22940

Answer (score 0):

I've just made a package that allows the customisation of the gutters and container margins per break-point: https://github.com/BenceSzalai/bootstrap-responsive-grid